# Prevent extensions from reading all page content

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Hello I was wondering if it is possible preventing Browser Extensions from reading all page content. For example I have an extension which allows me to get all emails and phone numbers in a page:
supposing I was the owner of the site, how can I prevent the extension from getting some data in my page?

Answer (score 2):

A web page can not prevent a browser extension from manipulating/reading the web page's DOM, manipulating the resources which are loaded into the page, or even preventing your site from being shown at all. The extension runs in a higher security context than the web page and is, or can be, running prior to your web page being loaded. The extension can exert whatever level of control over your page that it desires/is programmed.

You can try to obfuscate the information contained on the page such that the browser extension does not recognize the information as something it is trying to gather. Your ability to do this is limited, because the page has to be understood by the browser in order for it to be displayed to the user. If the browser extension is being actively written to work with your site, it will win.

Should an extension be written to specifically work with your site, if you are willing to put out the effort, you could update your web page faster than the extension is updated to deal with your updates. Extensions are updated relatively rarely, whereas the files for your web page could be written such that they are fetched every time the user visits the page. Thus, you could update your site to make the extension not recognize the information displayed shortly after the new version of the extension is uploaded for distribution, but before it propagates to (many) users. This would, obviously, be a substantial investment in time and effort to prevent some extension from working on your site. On the other hand, it would be a substantial effort on the part of the extension developer(s). It also assumes that the extension is being actively developed to work specifically with your site.

However, having a browser extension be actively written to work specifically with your site is a rare occurrence. Thus, a bit of obfuscation on your part could prevent many extensions from recognizing the data they are attempting to gather. Obviously, this is not preventing the extension from actually reading the any of the information on the web page, just making it such that the extension does not understand the information it read is the information it wants.

Comment: That was very informative, I am trying to acces the contents of a google calendar event page through my extension and there are some elements like their start time text box which cannot be accesed from the extension because they are in a Shadow DOM. So I think that answers Bite App's question - if you want to save your contents from the extension , put them in a Shadow DOM and make it a Closed DOM. A User Agent Shadow Element.

Comment: @sonali, Thanks. Using a Shadow DOM will make it more difficult for an extension to read info from the webpage (defined as all information transmitted when the user visits a URL, not just the DOM). However, if the the extension is targeted to the website, it will not categorically prevent the extension from obtaining the information. The extension, if it desires, could obtain the information from the JavaScript code which creates the Shadow DOM. Basically, if the information is transmitted to the user's machine, then an extension could gain access (except pages explicitly excluded by Chrome).

Comment: @sonali, For instance, the extension could just change the page's JavaScript to have that code conveniently pass the information to the extension without the need for the extension to scrape the DOM. Obviously, doing so would only work for an extension specifically targeted towards a particular site.

Comment: That is very interesting and good news to me. Since the past few weeks, I have been trying to access the shadow DOM of a google calendar event page and can't find a way. Can you please point me to some example or article about it?. I did ask the question on some forums and all I got was Shadow DOM's are not accesible. I agree that Shadow DOMs shouldn't be made inaccessible as it defeats the purpose of making DOM accessible to all.  If you vew the DOM of any Google calendar and look for the element that contains the Time, you will see what I mean. I appretialte the detailed answer.